# Binding Viewmodel error | XAML Parse Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I implement a small WPF application by using a MVVM pattern.
After I've setting the Datacontext in view.xaml. I got the following error.

[image: XAML Parse Exception]

XAML-Code

```
<control:CustomWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:eCustomWindow;assembly=eCustomWindow"
    xmlns:eControls="clr-namespace:eControls;assembly=eControls"
    xmlns:nGantt="clr-namespace:nGantt;assembly=nGantt"
    xmlns:GanttChart="clr-namespace:nGantt.GanttChart;assembly=nGantt" 
     xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
    x:Class="iView.Window_Absence"
    Title="Window_Absence" Height="914" Width="1599">


<control:CustomWindow.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ViewModel_Absence/>
</control:CustomWindow.DataContext>
```

My ViewModel

```
  namespace ViewModel

{
    public class ViewModel_Absence : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

    private readonly DatabaseContext _DataContext;


    public ViewModel_Absence()
    {
         this._DataContext = DatabaseContext.Instance;      
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

The code of the Databasecontext class. The Exception is the same one. It threw after filling the table employee with the adapter_employee.

```
    public class DatabaseContext
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the data set.
    /// </summary>
    public ForeCastDataSet DataSet { get; private set; }
    private const string DatabaseFileName = "ForeCast.xml";
    private static DatabaseContext instance;
    private String team = "C ITS, Western-Center";




   // Adapter für die "Datagrids"
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsuebersichtTableAdapter adapter_viewmonth;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.StammdatenTableAdapter adapter_master;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.AbwesenheitenTableAdapter adapter_absence;

    // Adapter zum befüllen von "ComboBox"
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.BundeslandTableAdapter adapter_state;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsauswahlTableAdapter adapter_month;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.ProfileTableAdapter adapter_profile;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.TeamAdapter adapter_team;


    // Abwesenheiten
 //   public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.UrlaubTableAdapter adapter_holiday;
    public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MitarbeiterTableAdapter adapter_employee;
//   public ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.AbwesenheitenplanungTableAdapter adapter_organiseAbsence;



    private DatabaseContext()
    {


        this.DataSet =  new DataModel.ForeCastDataSet();

        this.adapter_month = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsauswahlTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_month.Fill(this.DataSet.Monatsauswahl, this.team);
        // Adapter für neue Mitarbeiter initalisieren

        this.adapter_viewmonth = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsuebersichtTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_month = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsauswahlTableAdapter();
        this.addColumnsViewMonth();
        this.adapter_month.Fill(this.DataSet.Monatsauswahl, team);

        this.adapter_state = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.BundeslandTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_state.Fill(this.DataSet.Bundesland);

        this.adapter_team = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.TeamAdapter();
        this.adapter_team.Fill(this.DataSet.Team);

        this.adapter_master = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.StammdatenTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_master.Fill(this.DataSet.Stammdaten,this.team, 2018);

        this.adapter_profile = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.ProfileTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_profile.Fill(this.DataSet.Profile, this.team);

        this.adapter_absence = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.AbwesenheitenTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_absence.Fill(this.DataSet.Abwesenheiten);

        this.adapter_employee = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MitarbeiterTableAdapter();
        this.adapter_employee.Fill(this.DataSet.Mitarbeiter, this.team, 2018);


        this.adapter_viewmonth = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.MonatsuebersichtTableAdapter();
        ForeCastDataSet.MonatsuebersichtDataTable dt = new ForeCastDataSet.MonatsuebersichtDataTable();
        DateTime date = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        int month = date.Month;
        adapter_viewmonth.Fill(dt, team, month, 2018);

        this.DataSet.Monatsuebersicht.Merge(dt);


        // Abwesenheiten
     //  this.adapter_holiday = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.UrlaubTableAdapter();
      //  this.adapter_holiday.Fill(this.DataSet.Urlaub, this.team, 2018);

    //   this.adapter_organiseAbsence = new ForeCastDataSetTableAdapters.AbwesenheitenplanungTableAdapter();
     //  this.adapter_organiseAbsence.Fill(this.DataSet.Abwesenheitenplanung, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(25), this.team);




        if (File.Exists(DatabaseFileName))
        {
            // Load the existing database file.
          //  this.DataSet.ReadXml(DatabaseFileName);
            this.DataSet.AcceptChanges();
        }
        else
        {


        }
    }

 public static DatabaseContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance ?? (instance = new DatabaseContext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kindly paste your error in english.

Comment: or wait for us to learn German :D

Comment: can you check you get error even after commenting `this._DataContext = DatabaseContext.Instance;` ?

Comment: i added a translation

Comment: @RahulAgarwal after i Commenting the datacontext. The problem is solved. But I have a lot of other Viewmodels with any datacontext problems. do u have an idea?

Comment: @Frederik.Wagener : so `DatabaseContext.Instance` is culprit. can't you debug it ? to me it appears at runtime while parsing xaml it tries to create an instance of viewmodel which is failing.

Comment: if I delete the datacontext in my .XAML class. I have no problems. but i have to set it

Comment: @Frederik.Wagener `DatabaseContext.Instance` is null during the construction of `ViewModel_Absence`. Try setting the DataContext inside the view's constructor: `this.DataContext = new ViewModel_Absence();`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. After Debugging I think the problem is in the datacontext class. I added some code in my description

Comment: Please post the inner exception. The issue lies in the VM ctor, but we have neither the exception, nor the full code for DatabaseContext.Instance.

Comment: @Lennart i have added the full databasecontext class and some information above. thanks for help

Comment: There is no public Instance property in that class. And the private one you have is never initialized

Comment: @Lennart the property is initialized. i've forgot to add it

Comment: its solved! it was i simple foreign key problem :-)

Comment: Hey Frederick. You should look into an orm like entity framework or dapper. The actual database connection stuff should be in a model class rather than viewmodel. The viewmodel should call get... to just get a list of data and the model connects to the database, reads the data and returns the list.

Comment: @Frederik.Wagener Good to know. However, it doesn't remove the 2 architectural problems, mentionned by me and Andy

Comment: Thanks für the Great Support . I have to imporve my architecture

Answer (score 1):

IMO you have a design problem: you shouln't have your DataContext in the ViewModel, **ViewModel is DataContext**. The purpose of MVVM is to have View and ViewModel as decoupled as possible. For the sake of decoupling, interfaces are absolutely relevant.

I would do the following. As ViewModel:

```
public interface IMainViewModel : IViewModel {}
public interface IViewModel {}
public class MainViewModel : IMainViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged {}
```

In CodeBehind (MainWindow.xaml.cs) of the View:

```
public interface IView {}
public partial class MainWindow : IView
{
    public IMainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (IMainViewModel)DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow() // for design
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    }

    public MainWindow(IMainViewModel mainViewModel) // for DI
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

and in the View (MainWindow.xaml), make sure to have in the Window (or any View type) markup:

```
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance myns:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

As such you'll have an instance of your ViewModel available for your design as you work on the design, and you'll have also the proper ViewModel as you run. You can hence tune properties of your ViewModel for design (eg., with mocking) and have other values (maybe with a connexion to database or anything) for runtime.